# How to open different activities for each day in the custom calendar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, calendar

I downloaded a custom calendar and I want the calendar to open different activities depending on which day the user clicks. What should I write in the `public void onClick(View view)` in order to do so?

i tried the typical method to jump to another activity when it's clicked which is `**Intent intent= new Intent(view.getContext(), example.class); startActivityForResult(intent, 0);**` but i don't know what to write instead of the **example.class**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@TargetApi(3)
public class MyCalendarActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String tag = "MyCalendarActivity";

    private TextView currentMonth;
    private Button selectedDayMonthYearButton;
    private ImageView prevMonth;
    private ImageView nextMonth;
    private GridView calendarView;
    private GridCellAdapter adapter;
    private Calendar _calendar;
    private int month, year;
    private final DateFormat dateFormatter = new DateFormat();
    private static final String dateTemplate = "MMMM yyyy";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_calendar_view);

        _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) ;
        year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        Log.d(tag, "Calendar Instance:= " + "Month: " + month + " " + "Year: "
                + year);

        selectedDayMonthYearButton = (Button) this
                .findViewById(R.id.selectedDayMonthYear);
        selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: ");



        currentMonth = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
        currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
                _calendar.getTime()));



        calendarView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar);

        // Initialised
        adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /**
     * 

     */


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == prevMonth) {
            if (month <= 1) {
                month = 1;
                year--;

            } else {
                month--;

            }
            Log.d(tag, "Setting Prev Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
                    + month + " Year: " + year);

        }
        if (v == nextMonth) {
            if (month > 1) {
                month = 1;
                year++;

            } else {

                month++;
            }
            Log.d(tag, "Setting Next Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
                    + month + " Year: " + year);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(tag, "Destroying View ...");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    // Inner Class
    public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
        private static final String tag = "GridCellAdapter";
        private final Context _context;

        private final List<String> list;
        private static final int DAY_OFFSET = 1;
        private final String[] weekdays = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue",
                "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
        private final String[] months = { "January", "February", "March",
                "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                "October", "November", "December" };
        private final int[] daysOfMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30,
                31, 30, 31 };
        private int daysInMonth;
        private int currentDayOfMonth;
        private int currentWeekDay;
        private Button gridcell;
        private TextView num_events_per_day;
        private final HashMap<String, Integer> eventsPerMonthMap;
        private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd-MMM-yyyy");

        // Days in Current Month
        public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                int month, int year) {
            super();
            this._context = context;
            this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
            Log.d(tag, "==> Passed in Date FOR Month: " + month + " "
                    + "Year: " + year);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            setCurrentDayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            setCurrentWeekDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
            Log.d(tag, "New Calendar:= " + calendar.getTime().toString());
            Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfWeek :" + getCurrentWeekDay());
            Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfMonth :" + getCurrentDayOfMonth());

            // Print Month
            printMonth(month, year);

            // Find Number of Events
            eventsPerMonthMap = findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(year, month);
        }

        private String getMonthAsString(int i) {
            return months[i];
        }

        private String getWeekDayAsString(int i) {
            return weekdays[i];
        }

        private int getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(int i) {
            return daysOfMonth[i];
        }

        public String getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        /**
         * Prints Month
         * 
         * @param mm
         * @param yy
         */
        private void printMonth(int mm, int yy) {
            Log.d(tag, "==> printMonth: mm: " + mm + " " + "yy: " + yy);
            int trailingSpaces = 0;
            int daysInPrevMonth = 0;
            int prevMonth = 0;
            int prevYear = 0;
            int nextMonth = 0;
            int nextYear = 0;

            int currentMonth = mm - 1;
            String currentMonthName = getMonthAsString(currentMonth);
            daysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentMonth);

            Log.d(tag, "Current Month: " + " " + currentMonthName + " having "
                    + daysInMonth + " days.");

            GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 1);
            Log.d(tag, "Gregorian Calendar:= " + cal.getTime().toString());

            if (currentMonth == 11) {
                prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
                daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                nextMonth = 0;
                prevYear = yy;
                nextYear = yy + 1;
                Log.d(tag, "*->PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                        + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                        + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
            } else if (currentMonth == 0) {
                prevMonth = 11;
                prevYear = yy - 1;
                nextYear = yy;
                daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                nextMonth = 1;
                Log.d(tag, "**--> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                        + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                        + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
            } else {
                prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
                nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
                nextYear = yy;
                prevYear = yy;
                daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                Log.d(tag, "***---> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                        + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                        + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
            }

            int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
            trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;

            Log.d(tag, "Week Day:" + currentWeekDay + " is "
                    + getWeekDayAsString(currentWeekDay));
            Log.d(tag, "No. Trailing space to Add: " + trailingSpaces);
            Log.d(tag, "No. of Days in Previous Month: " + daysInPrevMonth);

            if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
                if (mm == 2)
                    ++daysInMonth;
                else if (mm == 3)
                    ++daysInPrevMonth;

            // Trailing Month days
            for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++) {
                Log.d(tag,
                        "PREV MONTH:= "
                                + prevMonth
                                + " => "
                                + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                                + " "
                                + String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth
                                        - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                                        + i));
                list.add(String
                        .valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                                + i)
                        + "-GREY"
                        + "-"
                        + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                        + "-"
                        + prevYear);
            }

            // Current Month Days
            for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
                Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
                        + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
                if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {
                    list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
                            + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                } else {
                    list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
                            + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                }
            }

            // Leading Month days
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size() % 7; i++) {
                Log.d(tag, "NEXT MONTH:= " + getMonthAsString(nextMonth));
                list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-"
                        + getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear);
            }
        }

        /**
         * NOTE: YOU NEED TO IMPLEMENT THIS PART Given the YEAR, MONTH, retrieve
         * ALL entries from a SQLite database for that month. Iterate over the
         * List of All entries, and get the dateCreated, which is converted into
         * day.
         * 
         * @param year
         * @param month
         * @return
         */
        private HashMap<String, Integer> findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(int year,
                int month) {
            HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            return map;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_gridcell, parent, false);
            }

            // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
            gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
            gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);



            Log.d(tag, "Current Day: " + getCurrentDayOfMonth());
            String[] day_color = list.get(position).split("-");
            String theday = day_color[0];
            String themonth = day_color[2];
            String theyear = day_color[3];
            if ((!eventsPerMonthMap.isEmpty()) && (eventsPerMonthMap != null)) {
                if (eventsPerMonthMap.containsKey(theday)) {
                    num_events_per_day = (TextView) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.num_events_per_day);
                    Integer numEvents = (Integer) eventsPerMonthMap.get(theday);
                    num_events_per_day.setText(numEvents.toString());
                }
            }

            // Set the Day GridCell
            gridcell.setText(theday);
            gridcell.setTag(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);
            Log.d(tag, "Setting GridCell " + theday + "-" + themonth + "-"
                    + theyear);

            if (day_color[1].equals("GREY")) {
                gridcell.setTextColor(getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.lightgray));
            }
            if (day_color[1].equals("WHITE")) {
                gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                        R.color.lightgray02));
            }
            if (day_color[1].equals("BLUE")) {
                gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orrange));
            }
            return row;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


        }

        public int getCurrentDayOfMonth() {
            return currentDayOfMonth;
        }

        private void setCurrentDayOfMonth(int currentDayOfMonth) {
            this.currentDayOfMonth = currentDayOfMonth;
        }

        public void setCurrentWeekDay(int currentWeekDay) {
            this.currentWeekDay = currentWeekDay;
        }

        public int getCurrentWeekDay() {
            return currentWeekDay;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what activities do you want to be triggered?

Comment: @ChrisBolton  
a blank activity with a picture and timer in it, so each day has it's activity with different picture and a timer in it

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @ChrisBolton well i tried the typical method to jump to another activity when it's clicked which is **Intent intent= new Intent(view.getContext(), example.class);
   startActivityForResult(intent, 0);** but i don't know what to write instead of the **example.class**.

Comment: put what you have tried in your post.

Comment: @ChrisBolton done. Now what?